# What is the asymptote for $f(x) = 3x + 1$ and $h(x) = 1 + \left( \frac{1}{3} \right)^x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am stuck. How do I find the asymptote for  $f(x) = 3^x + 1$  and $h(x) = 1 +    \left( \frac{1}{3} \right)^x$.

Comment: Not 3x+1 but 3^x+1, thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

In general, any function of the form $y = a^x$ has the asymptote $y=0$. Therefore, $y = 3^x$ has a horizontal asymptote $y = 0$. Since $3^x+1$ is just $3^x$ shifted up 1 unit, you can infer that its asymptote is $y = 1$.

You can do the same for $(1/3)^x$

Answer (score 0):

For f(x) = 3^x + 1, it has a horizontal asymptote y = 1 because as x --> - infinity, f(x) --> 1, and for g(x) = 1 + 3^(-x), it has a horizontal asymptote y = 1 as well since g(x) ---> 1 when x --> + infinity. Those are the only asymptotes for both functions.